# if elseif statement in a do/while statement infinite looping javascript

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, do-while

I'm trying to get my head round do/while loops and logical operators in js. My problem is when embedding a if/ else if/ else statement into the do section as it keeps looping the alerts. Also, if i type anything other than rare, medium or well-done it goes into the else if statement rather than the else statement even though I've specified medium or well-done for the else if statement. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
var food;
var steak;

food = prompt("Hey what type of food do you want to eat? We have steak,                  chicken, legumes, kangaroo or pufferfish?","Select your choice   here.").toUpperCase();

switch (food) {
    case 'STEAK':
        alert ("Sure no problem, how would you like your steak done?");
        steak = prompt("Would you like your steak done rare, medium or well-done?").toUpperCase();
            do {
                if (steak === "RARE") {
                    alert ("You eat the rare steak");
                }
                else if (steak === "MEDIUM"||"WELL-DONE") {
                    alert("You eat your steak and it's good.");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry didn't catch that.");
                    steak = prompt("Choose rare, medium or well-done.");
                }
            } while (steak !== "RARE" || "MEDIUM" || "WELL-DONE");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Syntax like `if (steak === "MEDIUM"||"WELL-DONE")` doesn't fly in JavaScript. You have to do each comparison individually. E.g. `if (steak === "MEDIUM" || steak === "WELL-DONE")`

Comment: @j08691 already pointed out how you need to do the comparisons. The reason for the infinite loop is that `"any string"` is truthy, ie. the comparison is the same as `while (steak !== "RARE" || true || true)` which is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going in infinite loop because of the condition you have in the 'while' construct always equates to "true".

What you have is as follows:

```
while (steak !== "RARE" || "MEDIUM" || "WELL-DONE")
```

Change it to

```
while (steak !== "RARE" && steak !== "MEDIUM" && steak !== "WELL-DONE")
```

Also, you have a similar problem in one of the 'else if' statements.

```
else if (steak === "MEDIUM"||"WELL-DONE") {
```

Change it to

```
else if (steak === "MEDIUM"|| steak === "WELL-DONE") {
```

There are still a few logical problems in your script. Try something like following instead:

```
var food;
var steak;

food = prompt("Hey what type of food do you want to eat? We have steak,                  chicken, legumes, kangaroo or pufferfish?","Select your choice   here.").toUpperCase();

switch (food) {
case 'STEAK':
    alert ("Sure no problem, how would you like your steak done?");

    steak = prompt("Would you like your steak done rare, medium or well-done?").toUpperCase();
    while (steak !== "RARE" && steak !== "MEDIUM" && steak !== "WELL-DONE") {
        alert("Sorry didn't catch that.");
        steak = prompt("Choose rare, medium or well-done.").toUpperCase();
    }

    if (steak === "RARE") {
        alert ("You eat the rare steak");
    }
    else if (steak === "MEDIUM"|| steak === "WELL-DONE") {
        alert("You eat your steak and it's good.");
    }            
    break;
}
```

Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do each comparison individually, so

```
else if (steak === "MEDIUM"||"WELL-DONE") {
    alert("You eat your steak and it's good.");
}
```

should be

```
else if (steak === "MEDIUM"|| steak === "WELL-DONE") {
    alert("You eat your steak and it's good.");
}
```

and so on.
This is also the cause of your infinite do/while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed above, the conditions have to be separately tested i.e
    if (a == n || a == m)

Also your last statement isn't correct. You might want to do something like

```js
var food;
var steak;

food = prompt("Hey what type of food do you want to eat? We have steak,                  chicken, legumes, kangaroo or pufferfish?","Select your choice   here.").toUpperCase();

switch (food) {
    case 'STEAK':
        alert ("Sure no problem, how would you like your steak done?");
        steak = prompt("Would you like your steak done rare, medium or well-done?").toUpperCase();
        console.log('steak', steak);
            do {
                console.log('steak inside do', steak);
                if (steak === "RARE") {
                    alert ("You eat the rare steak");
                }
                else if (steak === "MEDIUM"|| steak ==="WELL-DONE") {
                    alert("You eat your steak and it's good.");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry didn't catch that.");
                    steak = prompt("Choose rare, medium or well-done.").toUpperCase();
                }
            } while (steak !== "RARE" && steak !== "MEDIUM" && steak !== "WELL-DONE");
        break;
}
```

Worked for me .